# MSI not upgrading when ran under system account

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, psexec, windows-installer

I am running an MSI on a remote machine using PsExec using this command:

```
psexec -accepteula \\$(remote-machine-fqdn) -s cmd /c "msiexec.exe /qn /I $(path-to-msi) /Lv $(path-to-log-file)"
```

This works fine the first time, in that installs the application.

However, subsequent runs (and this is being run as part of a CI build in TFS) causes multiple versions of the application to appear in 'Add and Remove Programs'. If I run the installers myself (log on to the server, click on the MSI, etc.), then it upgrades correctly so the problem does not appear to be in installer itself.

I think the problem is to do with running as the system account (the -s switch in the PsExec command), but I can see no reason why this should be happening. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you looked at logs of upgrade process? Was your initial installer installed for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing ALLUSERS=1 public property to msi while fresh and upgrade installations.